# $_product->getQty() return 0 - Magento_Catalog default.phtml

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to override Magento/Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

With this code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>

<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_product->getQty() >= 1): ?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="status-instock"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php elseif($_product->isAvailable() && $_product->getQty() <= 0): ?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="status-preorder"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Preorder') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="status-outofstock"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It seem that $_product->getQty() always return 0

How can I get the true stock available for my products ?

Thank you in advance !

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

replace :

```
$_product->getQty()
```

by

```
$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty()
```

Please tell me if it's a good solution :)